# Firestore - If I give Document ID in Alphabetical Order will it create hotspots/inefficiency?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to build `users` collection which will have Documents with IDs as `A`,`B`,`C`,...`Z`.
Each Document will contain a subcollection which will contain data of all users with starting letter `A`,`B`,...`Z` depending on document ID.

In [Firestore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices) it is mentioned

> Do not use monotonically increasing document IDs such as:
> Customer1, Customer2, Customer3, ...
> Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, ...
> Such sequential IDs can lead to hotspots that impact latency.

So Does using alphabets as `Document ID` create the same issue and cause hotspots or some other in efficiencies?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could observe the same effect.  It's best to use fully randomized IDs like you get if you use `add()` to create a new document.